# How to show the column "Gender" to chart in Laravel from database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, charts, highcharts

I want to make a chart to show  how many responses by gender from the database. But, i don't know how to use the controller.

I write this in my controller

[image: the chart controller]

Comment: share your table and model

Comment: Hi @Loka, You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$Datetrains = DashboardTrain::where('promo', 'not like', 'Yes')->get();

$chart = Charts::database($Datetrains, 'bar', 'highcharts')
    ->title("Gender")
    ->elementLabel("Freq")
    ->dimensions(1000, 500)
    ->responsive(false)
    ->groupBy('gender');

    return view('Dashboard', compact('chart');
```